# What is the difference between 准时 and 按时?

Tags: difference, adverbs

These both seem to mean "on time" or "on schedule" (compared to 及时, which I believe means "in good time", i.e. before the scheduled / agreed time).

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: There is a video by a native speaker on this:
https://youtube.com/watch?v=TFtyee6nul8
《What's the difference between 按时 VS 及时 VS 准时》

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 准 = accurate; precise
>
> 准时 = **on time**/ on schedule (event or action take place at a **precisely** scheduled/ appointed time)

~

> 按 = according to; base on
>
> 按时 = **on schedule**/ on time (event or action take place **strictly** following a scheduled/ at an appointed time)
>
> Also: 按时 (base on hourly schedule/ on schedule timely), 按年(base on an annual schedule ) 按月(base on a monthly schedule ), 按人头 (base on head count)
>
> Example: 按时吃药, 按年交税, 按月付款, 按人头付款 ( Take medicine on schedule hourly/ timely, pay taxes base on an annual schedule , pay a sum base on a monthly schedule, pay a sum base on head count)

Note:

准时 can be adverb or adjective - you can say "he is always 准时" but not "he is always 按时" because 按时 is an adverb

Answer (score 1):

Good question, their difference is tiny and hard to catch.

准时 is emotionally neutral while 按时 is less neutral. To be more clear, 准时 is emphasising on the physical aspect of being on time, while 按时 is emphasizing on a person's behaviour of being on time. For example

> 火箭准时发射
>
> 我会按时到达

While you can still say

> 我会准时到达

but the emphasis is not quite the same.

Answer (score -1):

answer by web search,e.g. https://hinative.com/zh-CN/questions/206511  temari: 按时 in time, 准时 on time,...
jingjing: 准时是形容词，可以在句子里直接作谓语，比如，我一向很准时。
按时是副词，不可以说，我很按时....
 kittysama:按时带点被动性，准时更强调主动性。...

Comment: ' in time' is 及時 not '按时' ; 准时 can be adjective or adverb too 他一向准时 (adj); 准时(adv)上班. And yes, 按时 is an adverb

Comment: adjectives can function as adverbials (＂实用汉语语法＂：形容词的主要功能是修饰名词（作定语）,但有的形容词也能修饰动词（作状语）或补充动词（作补语）） the point seems to be that 准时、按时 both can function as adverbials (状语，s. above quotation from 实用汉语近义虚词词典）, but 按时 unlike 准时 is an adverb and cannot function as adjective，按时 bkrs:on time before deadline on schedule，iciba:in time: 迟早； 最后； 及时； 经过一段时间之后, but also:  in time, on time 这两个词组都可表示"按时"

Answer (score -1):

＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂：

> 按时（副）／及时（形）＂／准时（形） **［相同］**
> 都可以作状语，都表示在确定的时间内。＂按时、准时＂意思更接近，常可互换，但意思稍不同：＂准时＂表示＂在准确的时间＂，强调＂准＂，句中都有表示具体时间点的词语；＂按时＂指在预定或规定的时间，对时间的准确性要求不那么高，句中可以表示具体时间点的词语，也可以没有：（１）下午４点，飞往成都的CA２３７１次航班准时从白云机场起飞（按时✓及时✗）（２）晚上８点整，８６次列车准时到达北京车站。（按时✓及时✗）（３）每天早上６点，老王都会准时到操场上锻炼。（按时✓及时✗）（４）这份材料明天下午要用，请准时完成。（按时✓及时✗）（５）每次集体活动她都准时参加。（按时✓及时✗）（６）开幕式９点开始，请按时出席。（准时✓及时✗）（７）我每天早上８点按时上班。（准时✓及时✗）（８）如果不按时交电话费，电话就会被停掉。（准时✓及时✗）（９）请同学们按时交作业。（准时✓及时✗）（１０）他每天按时睡觉，按时起床，生活很规律。（准时✓及时✗）
>
> **［不同］** **１。**＂及时＂与＂按时、准时＂差别较大，不能互换。＂按时、准时＂所指的是一个规定的时间，而＂及时＂的时间是随事件的发生来确定的，表示＂在适当的、最需要的时候＂：（１）幸亏小王及时发现问题，要不然就会出大事故。（按时✗准时✗）（２）警察及时赶到，抓住了小偷。（按时✗准时✗）（３）如果不是他及时来取措施，后果会更严重。（按时✗准时✗）
>
> **２。**＂及时、准时＂都是形容词，可以受＂不＂和＂很、非常、特别＂等程度修饰，可以作谓语、补语、定语，但意思不同，不能互换；＂按时＂是副词，没有这些用法：（１）由于抢救不及时，病人没能醒过来。（按时✗准时✗）（２）这场雨很及时，正好赶在播种前。（按时✗准时✗）（３）警察来得非常及时，再晚一点，小偷就跑了。（按时✗准时✗）（４）由于得到了及时的治疗，本村良子很快就恢复了健康。（按时✗准时✗）（５）心理医生对她进行了及时的心理指导。（按时✗准时✗）（６）２３３路车常常不准时，乘客意见很大。（按时✗及时✗）（７）现在正好５点，你很准时。（按时✗及时✗）（８）李明是一个特别准时的人。（按时✗及时✗）（９）地铁是一种很准时的交通工具，一般不能延误。（按时✗及时✗）
>
> **３。**＂及时＂还表示＂马上、立刻＂，＂按时、准时＂没有这个意思：（１）有病要及时请医生看。（按时✗准时✗）（２）有什么情况要及时向领导报告。（按时✗准时✗）（３）如果发现问题，就应该及时想办法解决。（按时✗准时✗）